# Automatic cache sizing for sequences in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

I was trying to create a sequence in SQL Server 2012 using below T-SQL script:

```
Create Sequence ConteoCycling  
AS int   
START WITH 2
MINVALUE 0
MaxVALUE 4
INCREMENT BY 1   
GO
```

I gave it a min (0) and max (4) range values so that it recycles itself once the given range is consumed. After successful creation, I saw following message in the messages tab in output window of  SQL Server Management Studio. This message is my point of confusion :

> cache size is greater than the number of available values; the cache
>   size has been automatically set to accommodate the remaining sequence
>   values.

So the message says that it was able to set the cache size automatically. But, when I went into the properties window of the sequence from object explorer it doesn't show up any specific cache size but `Default size` cache option selected as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

My question is that -

Based on the range I've selected for my sequence if SQL Server engine is somehow able to guess the cache size required for running through this sequence then why it is not setting a specific size instead.

Why it still shows `Default Size` option selected? Is it somehow dynamic in nature if it is set to `Default Size` option? It will be great if someone can enlighten me on what the SQL Server engine is doing behind the scenes in regards to the cache size of the sequence during its creation and recycling process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This message is my point of confusion :
>
> cache size is greater than the number of available values; *the cache
> size has been automatically set to accommodate the remaining sequence values*

The *message*(in italics) is not correct ..See the [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/721322/sequence-cache-size-unexpected-results) raised for this and i am not able to repro the issue any more  on SQLServer 2016 developer edition.

**Relevant items from Connect item:**

> Thanks for reporting this. The behavior is overall correct. The message is meant as a hint that the cache size is greater than the number of remaining sequence values. In fact we are not storing a different value for the cache size than the one specified in the alter/create sequence statement.
>
> The actual bug here is the message stating something else. We will fix this for a future release.
>
> Posted by Jan [MSFT] on 4/27/2012 at 9:41 AM
> Thanks again for reporting this issue. We have fixed the message and the fix will be available in a future update of SQL Server.

Message i am getting on SQL2016 developer edition for your test scenario..

> The sequence object 'ConteoCycling' cache size is greater than the number of available values.